# read_json instead of open and json.load

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm currenly loading a DataFrame as follows:

```
with open('walcl.json', 'r') as file:
    df_walcl = pd.DataFrame(json.load(file)['observations'])
```

Is there a way to perform the equivalent using only `pd.read_json`?

I.e. something like this:

```
df_walcl = pd.read_json('walcl.json', ...)
```

Note that I'm loading the data from the `observations` component.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option to `read_json` that filters the JSON to a specific dictionary key. Your method looks best.